# Present a DataMatrix in iOS

Tags: ios, datamatrix

I want to present a DataMatrix from a given String in an iOS App (NOT a barcode), but can not found any working SDK, guide or even hint to a solution. The only thing I found was a way to READ it, but it looks like the AVFoundation can't be used to SHOW it.

Would be very thankful for every hint to this topic.

More infos about DataMatrices:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix

Comment: Have you looked at "Zebra Crossing" https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC or "onBarcode" http://www.onbarcode.com/products/iphone_barcode/barcodes/data_matrix.html ?

Comment: That was correct and worked - thank you!