# How to generate dataMatrix using CIFilter?

Tags: swift, barcode-scanner, cifilter, datamatrix

I am getting error:

> Value for key inputBarcodeDescriptor of type CIDataMatrixCodeDescriptor is not yet supported

```
let string = "tempValue&123"
let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
guard let data = data else {
    return nil
}

let descriptor = CIDataMatrixCodeDescriptor(payload: data, rowCount: 1, columnCount: 1, eccVersion: CIDataMatrixCodeDescriptor.ECCVersion(rawValue: 0))        
let inputParameter  = ["inputBarcodeDescriptor": descriptor]        
let datafilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBarcodeGenerator", parameters: inputParameter)        
let image = datafilter?.outputImage        
print(image)
```

Comment: This is irrelevant but shouldn't your `eccVersion` be `.v000`?

Comment: the raw value of 0 represent .v000

Comment: I _said_ it was irrelevant. Just better coding practice that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you should just believe this runtime warning. You can't create a barcode using a CIDataMatrixCodeDescriptor; the class is documented but it isn't actually working. Use a different CIBarcodeDescriptor subclass instead (such as CIAztecCodeDescriptor).

Comment: There are third-party libraries that can make a data matrix. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311257/present-a-datamatrix-in-ios for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

wow, I've just ran into this issue... in 2022 :D

message is still
*[api] Value for key inputBarcodeDescriptor of type CIDataMatrixCodeDescriptor is not yet supported*

so I filed a feedback, let's hope for the best, as there's no lightweight alternative to generate DataMatrix codes that I could find

Comment: Xcode 15.0 and still getting: `CIDataMatrixCodeDescriptor is not yet supported`